# does anyone know how to go about fixing this issue i ran into?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsunknownkeyexception

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key emailField.'

---

My project is on Xcode 9, using Swift 4 and firebase... I'm sorry for the way I'm asking but i don't really know how to go about asking this.

Comment: Sounds like you may have an outlet called `emailField` that hasn't been connected in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you not connected the IBOutlet for the emailField in Storyboard properly. Not connected or multiconnected.